# time complexity of non-inplace binary search

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory, binary-search

Assuming that binary search is called upon a subarray of approximately length n/2 and that there are at most three comparions at a level I came up with `T(n) = T(n/2) + 3` as a recurrence relation.

**But**: When I call binarySearch recursively isn't the cost of the slice proportional to n? Thus, isn't the solution then `T(n) = nlogn` rather than `logn`?

This is confusing to me. I checked Python's cost model, and (as expected) the cost of a slice is proportional to `n`.

Comment: Can you include the code in your question? I think you're saying that it performs an O(n) operation (slicing half the array) and so your recurrence relation is wrong (and your binary search is therefore a poor implementation).

Comment: If you physically "slice" and copy the sub-array, then yes..but normally when we doing binary search, no elements is physically moved...see @AbcAeffchen 's answer for a better explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, there can be a difference of the complexity of an algorithm and its implementation.

If you implement binary search in a recursive function, that takes a copy of a part of the input array, this array has to be generated in `O(n)`, so you are right, that this would lead to an overall complexity of `O(n log n)` (maybe worse, depending on what exactly you are copying).

So you should not implement it this way. Only hand over a reference to the array and min and max index values to limit the search to the part of the array you need. (or something like this)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + 3
log a / log b = 1
d = 1
```

Thus

```
O(n) = O(log n)
```